# GradleTest:test: Could not resolve org.junit and and any dependency

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I created an Gradle project in IntelliJ, and everytime I build I run into errors with the dependencies, its always something like

```
GradleTest:test: Could not resolve org.junit
```

and

```
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 100 ms
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
Could not resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1
Could not resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1
Could not resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1
Could not resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
```

Every dependency that I add will run into the same error, I am not in offline mode and my jdk is ok

my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Please add your build.gradle

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: What version of gradle are you using?

Comment: I am using version 7.4

Comment: Are you by any chance connected to a VPN (work for example) that might prevent you from downloading dependencies from Maven?

Comment: I am connected to my work VPN

Comment: If you can disable VPN temporarily and try running the build again

Comment: Does Gradle build from the command line work: `./gradlew build`? If it does not work, you should look into the networking configuration on your PC: for some reason, Gradle is unable to find remote Maven repositories to download dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late for this but (for some unknown reason), in my case 5.8.1 version was not reachable from IntelliJ, when I switched to 5.8.2 it worked.